# An alternative to static classes

Tags: java, static

So I'm currently using a static class called GameFile and it holds the game instance, the current map, the player posiition, the player name, player money, etc. Basically all the global info. I was wondering if there is an alternative to this?

This is how I currently set in the static class the game instance (as an example):

```
GameFile.gameInstance = new ChromeGame();
```

and then when I need to use the information I call

```
GameFile.gameInstance.addScreen(SplashScreen).
```

Comment: Sure: don't use static state; pass things around with an instance instead.

Comment: There is a sort of per-thread static you can use, but, being per-thread, it's of limited use.  Otherwise, as Louis says.

Comment: Developing your game as an object with state as opposed to a bunch of global data will make it a lot easier to expand your project, too.  Concurrent games?  If a game is an object, no problem ... instantiate a new game and give it to a thread.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it for a mobile game. You can have OOP concepts all through out and have all setters/getters, but in low type mobile devices, this "OOP" is costly.

```
public class GameData {

    public static Model activePlayerModel;
    public static GameMap currentMap;

    public static void load () {
        // read necessary data from external sources. e.g. a file
    }

    public static void updateMap () {
        // update currentMap
    }

    public static Model getActiveModel() {
        // get current model/set default/or read from file and return
    }

    public static GameMap getCurrentMap() {
        // e.g. Create a map or read map from a file, etc
        // return the map
    }

}
```

Now I can access GameData's members directly.

```
public class GameScreen extends Screen {

    Model playerModel;

    public GameScreen (Game game) {
        GameData.load();
        playerModel = Settings.activePlayerModel;   
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, well.  Only you can decide what is best for your needs.  If this code were only ever written and only ever maintained by you, and never made part of an exportable API .. then, sure.  Otherwise there are a number of places where the code you've shown runs against advice given by Joshua Bloch in Effective Java (public fields tie you to an implementation; use minimal visibility for encapsulation, etc).  I'm not sure that I am able to buy the thesis that procedurally written code is always significantly less resource expensive than well written object-oriented code.

Comment: @scottb Yea, read that and admire that book. But it is expensive in many cases when it comes to game development especially for mobile devices as I mentioned in my answer. You can check some here from official Android site: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html

Comment: I haven't read that document, but find it almost inconceivable that in a game pushing many thousands of pixels per second, doing computer opponent AI, or calculating physics of angry birds, that an occasional dereference or extra parameter on the stack is going to matter.

Comment: @user949300 You are close. But not/second, say 1/30th of a second. Now, do your OOP, and you might hit the 1 second and the game will look like slow mo birds that doesn't launch..I am referring to your FPS.

Comment: Also I should add, for game development, you do NOT need to make everything non-OOP way, just know when it's not suitable and when it is.